# customizing menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i already ahve a menu which is called using wp_nav_menu( $_menu_args ) where

```
$_menu_args = ['theme_location' => $_theme_location,
       'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav menu_top']; //custom theme
```

this generates the below navigation code:

```
<div class="menu-menu_top_logged-container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_top" id="menu-menu_top_logged">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-340" id="menu-item-340">
            <a href="blablabla" title="By Celebration">By Celebration</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-491 current-menu-item page_item" id="menu-item-491">
            <a href="blablabla" title="By Category">By Category</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-487" id="menu-item-487">
            <a href="blablabla" title="My Profile">My Profile</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-486" id="menu-item-486">
            <a href="blablabla" title="Help &amp; Support">Help &amp; Support</a></li>
    </ul?
</div>
```

i want to add a notification text next to only profile link, like:

```
<a href="blablabla" title="My Profile"><span class="badge">2</span>My Profile</a>
```

how can i achieve this using wp_nav_menu. need help on how to customize wp_nav_menu

thanks

Comment: Check this link for your problem https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/. and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

This will find your anchor tag by the title and add the badge class to it on the document load.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'a[title="My Profile"]').prepend('<span class="badge">2</span>');
})
</script>
```